# Uncaught (in promise): InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to convert base64 data to file obj then upload it where `base64Match` is array of base64 files data.

```
async convertFile(data) {
        const base64Regex = /data:image\/\w+;base64,([\s\S]+)/; 
          const base64Match = this.Frm.value.content.match(base64Regex); 
          if (base64Match) { 
          const base64String = base64Match[1]; 
          } 
          let _that=this;
          base64Match.forEach(e => {
            let fileData=_that.dataURItoBlob(e);
            console.log('filedata',fileData.size);
          });
}

 dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    const byteString = window.atob(dataURI);
    const arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    const int8Array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
      int8Array[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    const blob = new Blob([int8Array], { type: 'image/jpeg' });    
    return blob;
 }
```

but i'm getting this error :

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): InvalidCharacterError: Failed to
> execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly
> encoded. Error: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be
> decoded is not correctly encoded.

[image]

Any solution to fix this issue Thanks

Comment: Some questions please: why the `data` argument for `convertFile` (it doesn't appear to be used anywhere) and what is in `this.Frm.value.content` and, if it is a data url, why not use it to call `dataURItoBlob` directly? Of course validating its format first could be a good idea. The error message in the post, and the screen shot of a problem with loading a polyfill don't appear to be related - do you have two separate errors?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the issue with your code, but it's probably a lot easier to use `.fetch` on the data URI and use the response to create the buffer, e.g.:

```js
const dataUriToBlob = async (dataUri) => {
    const int8Array = await fetch(dataUri)
    .then(res => res.arrayBuffer())
    .then(buffer => new Uint8Array(buffer));
    const type = dataUri.slice(5, dataUri.indexOf(';'))
    const blob = new Blob([int8Array], { type });
    console.log(blob.size, blob.type);
}

dataUriToBlob(document.getElementById('img').src)
```

```html
<img id="img" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer can you pls check the above screenshot i'm getting this error